# How can i make active background color for two elements in nav menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu, html-lists

I have a vertical navbar menu with 2 blocks.
First is nav with icons, second is text of menu.
They have a different background colors. How i can make one background color for two active nav blocks?
[design of menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtTVH.png)

```html
<div class="menu__icons">
  <ul class="menu__list">
    <li>
      <a class="menu__item" href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50" alt=""></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="menu__item" href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50" alt=""></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="menu__item" href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50" alt=""></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="menu__item" href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50" alt=""></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="menu__text">
  <ul class="menu__list">
    <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">First</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Second</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Third</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Fourth</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/levan563/1g5ucmwq/2/

Comment: Can you please paste your all HTML code here.Your problem is not well defined yet.

Comment: @ibnelaiq added, but i still dont know is this good solution or not

Comment: Do you want to set both backgrounds to the same color or do you want it to be like in the image? Your problem is not clear

Comment: @Screenload to be like in the image. When elemets is active, icon and text need to have one background color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well basically if you want to toggle `.active` and you don't want two separate markup of list.

Notice that `font-awesome` is for demonstration purposes only.

```css
.menu__item {
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: left;
}

.menu__item.active {
  background-color: #e9ebfd;
}

.menu__item.active .menu__icon {
  background-color: #e9ebfd;
  border-left: 4px solid #2c39ec;
}

.menu__item.active .menu__title {
  background-color: #e9ebfd;
}

.menu__item a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu__icon {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  color: #2c39ec;
}

.menu__title {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 20px;
  color: #777777;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navigation-menu">
  <ul class="menu__list list-unstyled">
    <li class="menu__item active">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="menu__icon">
          <i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="menu__title">Main Dashboard</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="menu__icon">
          <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="menu__title">Profile</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="menu__icon">
          <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="menu__title">Finances</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="menu__icon">
          <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="menu__title">Titles</div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Related Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mhrabiee/dojL9get/28/

Comment: Your welcome. just careful about units (for example width: 250px) is only for demo. in your project its maybe something else. Also you may replace your own design icons with font awesome.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand take `active` class for both block's `li` and try to use font, svg icon or transparent background images instead of block images

```css
.menu__list .active {
   background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu__icons">
    <ul class="menu__list">
        <li><a class="menu__item active" href="#">
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material/24/000000/tailoring-for-men.png">
          </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="menu__text">
    <ul class="menu__list">
        <li><a class="menu__item active" href="#">First</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its doable using jQuery.

Assuming you have same number of list items in both blocks,

```
$(function(){
 $('.menu__list li').on('click', function() {
  var idx = $(this).index();
  $('.menu__list li').removeClass('active');
  $('.menu__list li:nth-child(' + idx + ')').addClass('active');
});
});
```

also add .active class in css  and give needed style to li items also

```
.active{
/**your style**/
}
.active > a{

}

.active img{

}
```